# Plane equation x units from point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to find the equation of a plane normal to a certain vector $<x_1, y_1, z_1>$, and x units from a given point, $(a,b,c)$. Normally this question would be trivial, and I would simply create an equation with the normal $<x_1, y_1, z_1>$, through the point $(a,b,c)$. But x units is the distance away from the point $(a,b,c)$, so what is this insinuating? I tried to use the distance formula for a point to a plane. Should I of instead used the distance formula from a line to a point? And then pick a random point on the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be two possible solutions. The supporting points can be directly calculated: Since $\nu = (x,y,z)^T$ is normal to the plane, we must move distance of $x$ along $\nu$ from point $p = (a,b,c)^T$:
$$p_{1,2} = p \pm \frac x{\|\nu\|_2} \nu$$
Will be the two points at distance of $x$ from $p$ where you can put a plane normal to $\nu$ through.

Comment: Thank you!! Is that $2$ suppose to be there though? Because I think you derived this formula from $ \vec v$ = $v* \hat{v}$, which can be rearranged to have $ \hat{v}$ = $\vec v/v$, indicating that the point must be moved x units in the $ \hat{u}$ direction.

Comment: @kat I'm not sure I understand, but $\|u\|_2$ refers to the usual euclidean metric, $\|u\|_2 = \sqrt{u\cdot u} = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n u_i^2 \right)^{\frac12}$. (That is, $\frac1{\|\nu\|_2} \nu$ is a vector of length $1$ in the same direction as $\nu$)

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, as although it makes sense to add the point with the vector multiplied by the distance, as it's demonstrating that the new point will be x distance above or below along the vector. But why would we have to divide by the length?

Comment: @kat If $\nu$ was longer than $1$ unit, $x\nu$ will be longer than $x$ unit, thus you need to normalize $\nu$ to a vector with length of $1$ unit: $\frac x{\|\nu\|_2} \nu$ will have length of $x$ units independent of the length of $\nu$.